# Does equality almost everywhere on a product imply equality almost everywhere on sections

Tags: measure-theory, integration, measurable-functions

(This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040105/equality-almost-everywhere-on-products) was on MSE, with no answers)

Consider two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $X=X_1\times X_2$ the product measure space (a priori non-completed).

Take two functions measurable functions $f$ and $g$ on $X_1\times X_2$ that are almost everywhere equal (meaning that the subset of $X_1\times X_2$ where there are not equal is a subset of a measurable set of measure zero). 
Is the following true :

- For almost all $x_1\in X_1$, "$f(x_1,\cdot)=g(x_1,\cdot)$" almost everywhere in $X_2$.

In the answer is negative, does it become positive when we consider a completed product measure ? or when all measures are completed ?

Comment: Yes, by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Which version of Fubini theorem are you using to prove this?

Comment: Just because you didn't get an answer on MSE doesn't make it suitable for MO. Look up Tonelli.

Comment: I suppose you are the downvoter. But I did look up Tonelli. Could you please explain to me how does Tonelli trivially imply this ?

Comment: Consider the characteristic function of the set $\{f\ne g\}$.

Comment: Actually the characterization of the null sets is the usual starting point when studying product measures.